# Conversion from Iplimage to Mat doesn't retain depth information

Tags: c++, opencv

Ok... I don't know what I'm missing, but the opencv documentation says that you can construct a Mat from an IplImage.  I have an IplImage, but after constructing the Mat, it loses the depth information.  I need to check the depth information before passing it into the calcHist function.

```
cout<<"image depth:"<<image->depth<<endl;
cout<<"image size: "<<image->height<<" "<<image->width<<endl;

Mat src(image);
cout<<"src   depth:"<<src.depth()<<endl;
cout<<"src   size: "<<src.size().height<<" "<<src.size().width<<endl;
```

My output looks like this.  Note that the depth information is GONE:

```
image depth:8
image size: 257 109
src   depth:0
src   size: 257 109
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it's correct because CV_8U==0. See [here](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/depth-alway-return-0-td6267914.html) for more details.

- When you load an image in `IplImage` structure the depth is set to `IPL_DEPTH_8U`, which is 8.
- When you load an image in `Mat` structure, the depth is `CV_8U`, which is 0.

I made a small test for an ordinary image:

```
Mat frame=imread(szImagefile,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
cout<<"image depth:"<<frame.depth()<<endl;
```

and the result:

```
image depth:0
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the depth would CHANGE when converting from IplImage to Mat.  I agree that if my IplImage was CV_8U, then my Mat should have a depth of 0.

Comment: @qwerty9967 It doesn't change. The depth for IplImage is set to IPL_DEPTH_8U, which is 8 and the depth for Mat is CV_8U, which is 0.

Comment: well... that explains it.  Thanks for the help.  Can you edit your response to include your comment in the response.  That was the point that I was missing.